# How to make ConnectOutput?

Tags: c#, logic, logical-operators

In C# i was making combinational logic, but for some reason i don't get how to make the ConnectOutput method for the example the AND gate.

this is the only description that i got: Connect an output of this component to an input of another component.
Allows multiple connections from the same output to other output pins

```
public class AndGate : ILogicComponent
    {
        bool value0;
        bool value1;


        public void ConnectOutput(int outputPin, ILogicComponent other, int inputPin)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool GetInput(int pin)
        {
            if (pin != 0 && pin != 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidPinException(pin + " is not a valid input pin for AND");
            }
            if(pin == 0)
            {
                return value0;
            }

            return value1;       
        }

        public bool GetOutput(int pin)
        {
            if (pin != 0 && pin != 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidPinException(pin + " is not a valid input pin for AND");
            }
            return value0 & value1;
        }

        public void SetInput(int pin, bool value)
        {
            if(pin != 0 && pin != 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidPinException(pin + " is not a valid input pin for AND");
            }
            if(pin == 0)
            {
                value0 = value;
            }
            if(pin == 1)
            {
                value1 = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the posted architecture there is no real way to connect components. When the 'other' component changes value there is no way for the AndGate to know that or update its values.

There are two main approaches to fix this:

1. Only compute values on demand
2. When a component changes value it informs all components that depend on its value that they should be updated.

The first approach is much easier to implement, but requires all values to be updated each time the output is desired. The second approach can allow for on-demand and partial updates.

An example of the first approach could be something like this:

```
public interface IComponent
{
    bool Value { get; }
}

public class AndComponent : IComponent
{
    private readonly IComponent[] input;
    public AndComponent(params IComponent[] input) => this.input = input;
    public bool Value => input.All(i => i.Value);
}
public class OrComponent : IComponent
{
    private readonly IComponent[] input;
    public OrComponent(params IComponent[] input) => this.input = input;
    public bool Value => input.Any(i => i.Value);
}
public class InputComponent : IComponent
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```